# Spark SQL count() returns wrong number

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Apache Spark and Scala (also a beginner with Hadoop in general).
I completed the Spark SQL tutorial: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html
I tried to perform a simple query on a standard csv file to benchmark its performance on my current cluster.

I used data from https://s3.amazonaws.com/hw-sandbox/tutorial1/NYSE-2000-2001.tsv.gz, converted it to csv and copy/pasted the data to make it 10 times as big.

I loaded it into Spark using Scala:

```
// sc is an existing SparkContext.
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

// createSchemaRDD is used to implicitly convert an RDD to a SchemaRDD.
import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD
```

Define classes:

```
case class datum(exchange: String,stock_symbol: String,date: String,stock_price_open: Double,stock_price_high: Double,stock_price_low: Double,stock_price_close: Double,stock_volume: String,stock_price_adj_close: Double)
```

Read in data:

```
val data = sc.textFile("input.csv").map(_.split(";")).filter(line => "exchange" != "exchange").map(p => datum(p(0).trim.toString, p(1).trim.toString, p(2).trim.toString, p(3).trim.toDouble, p(4).trim.toDouble, p(5).trim.toDouble, p(6).trim.toDouble, p(7).trim.toString, p(8).trim.toDouble))
```

Convert to table:

```
data.registerAsTable("data")
```

Define query (list all rows with 'IBM' as stock symbol):

```
val IBMs = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM data WHERE stock_symbol ='IBM'")
```

Perform count so query actually runs:

```
IBMs.count()
```

The query runs fine, but returns res: 0 instead of 5000 (which is what it returns using Hive with MapReduce).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filter(line => "exchange" != "exchange")`

Since "exchange" is equal to "exchange" filter will return a collection of size 0. And since there is no data, querying for any result will return 0. You need to re-write your logic.

Comment: I thought this was the way to remove the first line (containing headers) in Scala. So how do I remove the first line when reading in a csv file?

Comment: `filter(line => line != "exchange")`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I did not try it out: I got tired of the headers and just hard deleted them from the csv file.